# How do I port a serial port device driver from Linux 2.6.21 to 2.6.36?

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, device-driver

It appears that some time between these two kernels a lot of data structures were changed, and it breaks my driver in several places.

First, in 2.6.21 the struct uart_port had a field "struct uart_info *info" which I relied on in several places.  I test several places to make sure it is non-null, and if non-null I additionally test if it's sub-field (struct tty_struct *tty) is non-null, and I uses these to check if flow control is enabled and if we are stopped transmitting.

In 2.6.36 the info back pointer has been removed and I'm not sure how to get at it, or if the semantics of what I am trying to do are even valid any more, as the only serial driver that even uses this appears to have ifdef'ed out the code dealing with it, and additionally holds all this data in its own structures (how does that work to even correctly maintain state with the kernel)???

Additionally, save_and_cli() and restore_flags() are missing.   I see new functions local_irq_save() and local_irq_restore(), can I just switch to using those, or are there any gotchas?

Finally, __ioremap is missing. Looks like maybe ioremap_noncache is the replacement, but again I'm not sure if there are any semantic differences or gotchas. I would assume I don't want ioremap() since I am talking directly to hardware, but some other drivers appear to do so and I don't know why that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at how an in-tree driver that uses the same functionality has changed between the two versions is usually the best way to go.  For example, the `ioc4_serial` driver uses the `info` member of `struct uart_port` in [kernel 2.6.21](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.21/drivers/serial/ioc4_serial.c#L1630), but has switched to using the `struct uart_state *state` member by [kernel 2.6.36](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/drivers/serial/ioc4_serial.c#L1630).

That driver obtains the `tty_struct` with:

```
state = the_port->state;
tty = state->port.tty;
```